# Close Main Tkinter Window Without Ending Program

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, self, toplevel

My code is below. It is a very simple UI for logging into my program. The program has multiple `TopLevel()` instances branching from it, excluded for relevance and brevity. My issue is that once the user logs in, and a top-level instance appears, the main window(below) stays open in the background. Running both `self.quit()` and `self.destroy()` methods in the functions of the topLevel instances terminate the entire program instead of simply closing the main window. I believe it is due to how I declared my class but I do not know how to fix it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
class SampleApp(tk.Tk):
  def __init__(self):
    tk.Tk.__init__(self)

    self.KTitle = tk.Label(self, text="Login ")
    self.KTitle.grid(row=2,column=0, sticky=E)
    self.KUsername = tk.Label(self, text="Username: ")
    self.KUsername.grid(row=3,column=0, sticky=E)
    self.KPassword = tk.Label(self, text="Password: ")
    self.KPassword.grid(row=4,column=0, sticky=E)
    self.KUEntry = tk.Entry(self, width=15)
    self.KUEntry.grid(row=3,column=1, sticky=W)
    self.KUPass = tk.Entry(self, show = '*', width=15)
    self.KUPass.grid(row=4,column=1, sticky=W)
```

Comment: Your code doesn't show any Toplevel widgets.

Comment: I left those out for brevity. I didn't think I'd need to show the toplevel widgets in order to find the solution, but can add one of my toplevel instances if needed.

Comment: You need to create an [mcve]. If part of the problem involves other windows, you need to show at least one other window.

Comment: Best practice is to use a Toplevel window to do authentication/login, then you can safely destroy() the Toplevel window when you're done with it, without quitting the program. If you're worried about the main Tk window being displayed during login, you simply wm_withdraw it, and after login is complete, wm_deiconify the main window.